# How to overload getter in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a getter of place in a react class component which extracts data from mobx. There is a field with menu inside model place.

When I write this.place.menu to handle and take information from another resource not from mobx. I would like to overload a getter place

```
get place() {
  return this.mobx.place
}

componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.place.menu) // show mobx model
}
```

Comment: If I get your question: you shouldn't call `this.place.menu` if you don't mean it, but call another method, e.g. `getInitialMenu()` which isn't related to `mobx` at all.

Comment: First of all kind of the word you're looking for is probably not overload. Secondly, you could accomplish this by having the accessor return an object which wraps the mob value.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that we can play around with in our own IDEs.  Also, does this question depend on react and mobx? If so you might want to tag it as such.  If not, you might want to replace references to these with native TypeScript types and values, or define them in your example code.